# React js: dependency JSON.stringify(array) does not trigger useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I coded the process of acquiring new access token via refresh token, and sending the new access token to get the data. When I send get request I check if the status code is unauthorized or not, if so,I set `unauthorized` to `true`. It triggers the `useEffect`  then it sends the refresh token and gets the access token, and I update the `data` array. I expect the `useEffect` to reload one more time as I set the data array as dependency `JSON.strigify(data)` but   it does not trigger reload. Why? My code below:

```
import Style from '../style/h1.module.css'
import axios from 'axios'
import {useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import style_for_table from  '../style/table.module.css'

const List =()=>{
    const[data,set_data]=useState([]);
    const[unauthorized,set_unauthorized]=useState(false)
  
 useEffect(()=>{
    let token=localStorage.getItem('refresh_token') 
    if(unauthorized){
        console.log("expired")
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_refresh_token/',{refresh:token})
        .then((response)=>{
            localStorage.setItem('access_token',response.data.access)  //requesting access if the previous expired
        })
    }
    let config={
        headers:{
            Authorization: "Bearer"+ " " + localStorage.getItem('access_token')  
        }
    }
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/',config) //requesting data
    .then(res=>{
       if(res.status !== 401){
        set_data(res.data.map(element=>
            <tr>
                <td>{element.name}</td>
                <td>{element.price}</td>
                <td>{element.expiration_date}</td>
            </tr>  ),
                )
              }
       return res
    })
    .catch((res)=>{
        if(res.response.status==401){
           console.error("TOKEN EXPIRED AND NEW TOKEN ADDED")
           set_unauthorized(true) 
        }
    })

 },[unauthorized,JSON.stringify(data)])

    return(
        <> 
          <table className={style_for_table.table}>
          <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
                  <th>Expiration Date</th>
              </tr>
              {data}
          </table>  
      </>
    )
}
export default List
```

Comment: Did you try passing data as a dependency directly to useEffect? Instead of JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: array is object type  each time it's created regardless of the content the useEffect sees it as new  array so it causes infinite update